# How to write changes from one ManagedObject to similar ManagedObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am new with Core Data and have a problem which sounds trivial to solve (at least thinking in SQL) but I can't get my head around that with Core Data.

What I'm trying to do is the following: I have a fetched ManagedObject, do some changes and save it again. This ManagedObject has an attribute id. I want to write the changes I made to this ManagedObject to all the ManagedObjects with the same id.

I was thinking to overwrite `willSave:` and fetching the other ManagedObjects with the same id there but this won't work because I would encounter an infinite loop there.

Can somebody give me a hint on how to progress from here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Share your code then only we can help you , blindly how can i say this   ?

Answer (score 1):

You could make `willSave` work, but it isn't going to be a nice bit of code to ignore all of the invalid triggers.

It's better to have a class which manages this functionality, pass in the new data value and the attribute id and allow it to do the fetch and update all of the fetched objects (and trigger the save).

Comment: Thanks for your insight, that does indeed sound like the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would, indeed, try to find some better way to deal with it, because actually you should't think of Core Data as of SQL with its triggers.

But actually you can indeed use `willSave` method and avoid infinite loop. See 
[NSManagedObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/willSave) willSave method

> If you change property values using primitive accessors, you avoid the possibility of infinite recursion, but Core Data will not notice the change you make.

So basically in your willSave method you'll need to call some fetchRequest to get all instances of the same Entity, then loop through them and update using primitive accessor: [setPrimitiveValue:forKey:](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/setPrimitiveValue:forKey:)

Also I would advice to verify objects in loop whether they are removed (-isDeleted) and, probably, whether that object is not your current one (by comparing managedObjectIDs)

Comment: This is also an interesting approach. If I perform `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:`, how can I finally make Core Data save these changes? Do I have to somehow manually stage them for saving?

Comment: If I invoke `willChangeValueForKey:` `didChangeValueForKey:` I also encounter an infinite loop

Comment: Of course, if you call "willChangeValueForKey" it will be the same as if you directly change attributes. That's why you need to use primitive accessors - to avoid cascade changes and loop. As for saving those objects, I think you don't need to do anything. You're calling save on context, not on some object. Your changed objects will be fetched to the same context, where you have your original object, so you save this context and it should save everything. I can't be sure, but it's easy to test, just save and fetch objects and check.

Comment: Yes, but if I don't do that, those changes made by `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` are omitted for the next Managed Context save